# Inconsistent Object.is logic with NaN

Tags: javascript

This code evaluates to `false`:

```
Object.is(parseFloat('26-broadway'), NaN); // returns false
```

However this example evaluates as `true`:

```
Object.is(parseFloat('broadway-26'), NaN); // returns true
```

I would have expected the last code snippet to return `false` though. Why does it return `true` when I paste it in a Browser console like Google Chrome?

Comment: `parseFloat('broadway-26')` clearly is `NaN`. Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)? _“`parseFloat()` picks the longest substring **starting from the beginning** that generates a valid number literal.”_ It parses a string from left to right. `b` is not a digit, so it stops right there. How is `Object.is` even remotely related here?

Comment: I missed that part from left to right. Thank you!

Comment: It's not related. I should have used a better example related to parseFloat only. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `console.log(parseFloat('26-broadway'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sebastian pointed out, the real question has nothing to do with `Object.is` and all about the `parseFloat()`.

> “parseFloat() picks the longest substring starting from the beginning that generates a valid number literal.” It parses a string from left to right. b is not a digit, so it stops right there.